# Which is bigger, $ \log_{1000} 1001$ or $\log_{999} 1000 $?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, number-comparison

> Which is bigger, $ \log_{1000} 1001$ or $\log_{999} 1000 $?

I've tried using the identity of $\log_n x = \dfrac 1 {\log_x n} $, but didn't find a solution though. Any suggestions? or clues I can use?

Comment: It doesnt let me make it look correct, it's supposed to be log 1000 of 1001 and log 999 of 1000

Comment: I've edited it for you and for future reference use { } to enclose something when it is more than one character

Comment: Thanks! I thought I only needed to enclose the thing inside of the log

Comment: i think you didnt find a solution because they both are equal

Comment: @TheIntegrator : One should also note that things like \infty, \tan, \emptyset, etc. are _not_ "more than one character". $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy oh Hi Michael, you've helped me in the past. Cool to see you here

Comment: I mean, I couldn't simplify themfurther, How do I go about solving this type of questions? I usually get stumped with those @TheIntegrator

Comment: @MichaelHardy i meant cases when you are using number such as $123\cdots$. You are correct , but even if OP enclosed what you mentioned it would make no difference in the formatting

Comment: @TheIntegrator : What makes you conclude that they're equal?

Comment: @TheIntegrator They are not equal.  Plug into wolfram alpha.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Okay i'll level with you , i plugged it into my calc  and got the same value,

Comment: @TheIntegrator That's because they match up to 6 decimal places!

Comment: Can you use calculus? It's easy to show that $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\log (x+1)}{\log x} < 0$.

Comment: @Dzoooks oh you're right , silly me!!

Comment: @ConnorHarris Thanks, I think I got it. Good answer!

Comment: @ConnorHarris perhaps you could turn that into an answer. might be useful for future readers as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\log(x+1)}{\log x} = \frac{\frac{\log x}{x+1} - \frac{\log (x+1)}{x}}{\log^2 x} < 0,$$ so $\log_{999} 1000$ is larger.

Answer (score 5):

Use the fact that $\log_nx=\frac{\log x}{\log n}$ and then pick your favourite way to show that
$$\log(999)\log(1001)<(\log(1000))^2.$$

Comment: One easy way: take logarithms of both sides and then note that $\log \log x$ is concave. This is basically Lord Shark the Unknown's answer.

Comment: Alternatively, note that $\log^2 1000 > (\log 1000 + \log \frac{1001}{1000}) (\log 1000 - \log \frac{1001}{1000}) = \log 1001 \log \frac{1\,000\,000}{1001} > \log 1001 \log 999$.

Answer (score 3):

The question is, for $n=1000$, which is larger
$$\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}\qquad\text{or}\qquad\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n-1)}?$$
Or equivalently, is
$$\ln\ln(n+1)-2\ln\ln n+\ln\ln(n-1)$$
positive or negative?

Let $f(x)=\ln\ln x$. Then
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x\ln x}.$$
This is decreasing for $x>1$, and so $f$ is concave. Then
$f(n+1)-2f(n)+f(n-1)<0$
and so
$$\log_{1000}1001<\log_{999}1000.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let  $$ f(x)= \log _{x}(x+1) = \frac {\ln (x+1)}{\ln (x)} \text { for } x>1$$  Upon differentiation we get

$$ f'(x) = \frac {x\ln x -(x+1) \ln (x+1) }{x(x+1) (\ln x)^2} <0$$

Thus f(x) is decreasing.

As a result $$ log_{1000}1001<log_{900}1000 $$

Comment: just a question, I also got the derivative when I did this. How can I prove the derivative is decreasing?

Comment: The derivative is negative so the function is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM
$$\log_{999}1000-\log_{1000}{1001}=\frac{\ln1000}{\ln999}-\frac{\ln1001}{\ln1000}=\frac{\ln^21000-\ln1001\ln999}{\ln999\ln1000}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\ln^21000-\left(\frac{\ln1001+\ln999}{2}\right)^2}{\ln999\ln1000}=\frac{\ln^21000-\ln^2\sqrt{1001\cdot999}}{\ln999\ln1000}=$$
$$=\frac{\ln^21000-\ln^2\sqrt{1000^2-1}}{\ln999\ln1000}>\frac{\ln^21000-\ln^2\sqrt{1000^2}}{\ln999\ln1000}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\ge2$. If we write $a^2=x-1$ and $b^2=x+1$ with the understanding that $a,b\ge1$, then we see that

$$1\lt\sqrt3=\sqrt{4-1}\le\sqrt{x^2-1}=ab=\sqrt{x^2-1}\lt x$$

Thus we have $0\lt\log(ab)\lt\log x$ as well as $0\le\log a\lt\log b$. In particular, the positivity of the logs implies $(\log(ab))^2\lt(\log x)^2$, which we'll use shortly.

Using the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean inequality at a critical juncture (as in Michael Rozenberg's answer), we have

$$\begin{align}
\log(x-1)\log(x+1)
&=\log(a^2)\log(b^2)\\
&=4\log(a)\log(b)\\
&\le(\log a+\log b)^2\quad\text{(by AGM)}\\
&=(\log(ab))^2\\
&\lt(\log x)^2
\end{align}$$

Applying this with $x=1000$, we find

$$\log_{1000}1001={\log1001\over\log1000}\lt{\log1000\over\log999}=\log_{999}1000$$